# how to pass value query string

Tags: jquery

How do i send parameter value via querystring my query string url is http://ec2-18-222-171-156.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/api/products/delete?id=4 but i could send pass. could you please resolve my issues.

My code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".products-data .delete", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');         
        if (confirm('Delete this product?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'http://ec2-18-222-171-156.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/api/products/delete',
                dataType: 'json',   
                data :  {id : id},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(callback) {
                    console.log("Delete response"+callback);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(this).html("error!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't send pass my id value please solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The `data` parameter is only appended to the URL automatically for `GET` requests. Since you're using `DELETE`, you need to do it yourself.

```
url: 'http://ec2-18-222-171-156.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/api/products/delete?id=' + id
```

In your `success` function, `callback` is an object. If you want to concatenate it with a string, use `JSON.stringify`.

```
success: function(callback) {
    console.log("Delete response: " + JSON.stringify(callback));
},
```

Comment: i am using above method but can't get response my response is :Delete response[object Object] can you give fiddle example

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to display the response.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax type :PUT / POST and pass the parameter backend side function or check the id value

Answer (score 0):

hello pass data with ajax call and call your method with parameters

```
public object delete(int id)
 {

      //your code
}
$(document).on("click", ".products-data .delete", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');         
        if (confirm('Delete this product?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'http://ec2-18-222-171-156.us-east- 
                 2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/api/products/delete',
                dataType: 'json',   
                data :  {id : id},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(callback) {
                    console.log("Delete response"+callback);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(this).html("error!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```